Clarification on the nature of the Cantor set in the algebra of Baire sets modulo meager sets
Let $X$ be the Stone space of a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra $A$. I know that $A$ is isomorphic to the algebra $Ba(X)/M$ of Baire subsets of $X$ modulo meager set and that the Cantor set is an example of meager set in $M$. But what Cantor set are we talking about exactly? For the the Cantor set is a subset of $[0,1]$ not $X$? Any clarification would be welcome.
